# Follow-up person via Graph API Explorer facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to send a follower to sing through Graph API Explorer facebook

```
FB.api( '/me', 'POST', {"fields":"id,name"}, function(response) { // Insert your code here } );
```

Comment: So what? what do you want to say to us?

Comment: I want to know how to send a follow up via Graph API Explorer facebook

Comment: Not to me explain it to everyone from editing the question. Bcuz without explonation no one can give you a better solution. BTW you need to read: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: You can not make a user follow another person via API.